# PHPExcel throws fatal error while calling getHighestRow() if rangeToArray is used

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to read excel data in which i am able to call getHighestRow() normally if do not set any rangeToArray.

But the same throws error if I use rangeToArray for A1:Z2502.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getHighestRow() on a non-object

**My Code:**

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
//Read max of 2500 rows...
$objSheet=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray("A1:Z2504", null, true, true, true);
$no_of_rows=$objSheet->getHighestRow();echo $no_of_rows;
```

Comment: `rangeToArray` method return `array`. whereas `getHighestRow` is method of `PHPExcel_Worksheet` class. So you cannot use `getHighestRow` in your case. use `array_*` functions instead.

Comment: @hindmost : So whats the equivalent code to find getHighestRow ?

Comment: `getHighestRow` return highest row number on entire worksheet in any case. `rangeToArray` and any other methods cannot affect on this result.

Comment: @hindmost I write the code but he didn't try. Therefore, he couldn't find.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it.

**Code**

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWorksheet->rangeToArray("A1:Z2504", null, true, true, true);
```

**Edited Code**

```
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);  
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();

$headingsArray = $objWorksheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1',null, true, true, true);
```

If you use these codes, you can get highest values of excel.

Comment: you missed to tell how to find getHighestRow() ?

Comment: I didn't missed that. If you write these codes, you will get the highest row via getHighestRow method.

Comment: You have an error which is `Fatal error: Call to a member function getHighestRow() on a non-object` . My codes handle this problem.

Comment: Are u sure ? `$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);` what is it ? Why I added this ?

Comment: i tried it , still same error : `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PHPExcel::rangeToArray() `

Comment: Could you please upload your excel file ? I am using Excel Script in my own host and It is okay.

Comment: It ignores the A:Z range; calculates for overall sheet. How to calculate excel formula ? i can find length from it...

Answer (score 0):

You don't **set** `rangeToArray()`: so it cannot possibly ever affect a subsequent call to `getHighestRow()`. A call to `rangeToArray()` simply returns data from the worksheet object as a standard PHP [array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), it doesn't set anything, or return anything special.

If you are trying to call `getHighestRow()` on a PHP array, then it will return an error, because PHP arrays don't have methods. You can only call `getHighestRow()` on a worksheet object.

If you want to know how to get the size of a PHP array, you use PHP's own `count()` function

e.g.

```
$lastRow = count($objSheet);
```

though this will only work when your range started from row #1

**EDIT**

Alternatively, you're calling `rangeToArray()` with the `$returnCellRef` argument as `true`, so the resulting array will be indexed by the spreadsheet row and column.

This means that:

```
end($objSheet);             // move the internal pointer to the end of the $objSheet array
$lastRow = key($objSheet);  // fetches the key of the element pointed to by the internal pointer
```

will return $lastRow with the row number of the highest row number in the $objSheet array

**EDIT #2**

How to load only cells A1-Z2504 from a spreadsheet file:

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel5'; 
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls'; 


/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter  */ 
class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter 
{ 
    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') { 
        //  Read rows 1 to 2504 and columns A to Z only 
        if ($row >= 1 && $row <= 2504) { 
            if (in_array($column, range('A','Z'))) { 
                return true; 
            } 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
} 

/**  Create an Instance of our Read Filter  **/ 
$filterSubset = new MyReadFilter(); 

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/ 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType); 
/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/ 
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset); 
/**  Load only the rows and columns that match our filter to PHPExcel  **/ 
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
```

**Yet another EDIT**

What you're trying to do becomes less and less clear whenever you add comments.

If you need to know how many rows and columns there are in a worksheet ***before*** loading it, then each reader implements a `listWorksheetInfo()` method that returns an array of details about each spreadsheet file

Comment: you meant `Excel count()` function ?

Comment: NO! I mean the PHP count() function, which will return the number of entries in an array

Comment: it can be used only after storing the data into array. I want it before storing the data into array . as I need to do some checks before storing excel data into array

Comment: You __are__ storing the data in an array, that's what your call to `rangeToArray()` does

Comment: Are you trying to implement a read filter so that load() only reads rows 1-2504?

Comment: I am trying to apply filter from A1:Z2504;
other columns may have values more than 2504 which i dont want for this calculation

Comment: I actually wanted to read no.of. rows present inside the excel and then run the loop. you are running the loop for 2500+ iterations. `if ($row >= 1 && $row <= 2504)`

Comment: Then please explain __exactly__ what you're trying to do in simple terms that somebody as stupid as myself can understand..... but an `if` test is __not__ a loop in PHP (or any other computer programming language that I'm aware of)

Comment: I am sorry if it is not clear. I said in my question that ,i need to find out no.of rows immediately after setting array range as below but it is working is my query. `$objSheet=$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray("A1:Z2504", null, true, true, true);
$no_of_rows=$objSheet->getHighestRow();echo $no_of_rows;`

Comment: THEN USE THE METHOD I SHOWED IN MY FIRST EDIT HERE: `end($objSheet);
$$no_of_rows = key($objSheet); echo $no_of_rows;` but you are not __setting__ any array range, you are __retrieving__ a range of cells to an array

Comment: Thanks... is key($objSheet) applicable for entire sheet or particular range which we set? as i look for no.of rows in A1:Z2504 only !

Comment: `key($objSheet)` is applicable to any PHP __array__... it returns the key of the current array element.... it has nothing to do with Worksheets or Ranges because PHP has no concept of Worksheets or Ranges

Answer (score -2):

I found a workaround solution for this..

Added a formula in Excel `COUNTA()` to find number of filled rows..
and then read the row by

```
$objSheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2,1)->getCalculatedValue()
```

Comment: This isn't a workround, I can't understand why you need to do this at all. `rangeToArray()` does not in any way affect, nor is it affected by, any call to `getHighestRow()`. The `getHighestRow()` method returns the highest row number in a PHPExcel_Worksheet object, not of a PHP array

Comment: @MarkBaker : I need to get the highest row value on a particular range of cells.. If the work sheet has other objects which i am not looking for as getting calculated when i use `getHighestRow()` ;

Comment: I am not sure who upvoted OEASLAN answer which is not solving my question !!